# Sitecore - Export "My Toolbar" to package

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I would like to be able to export content editor's 'my toolbar' to a package so that whenever I restore the db on my dev machine I can also restore my buttons.

Where are those settings stored? I have looked all around in the core database and can't find it. The closest I have come is content\documents and settings{user name}...but my user name is not listed there.

Sitecore 6.6

Answer (score 1):

It is saved in Sitecore "Registry": Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Registry. It is wrapper under user profile entity. Toolbar buttons are saved by "/Current_User/Ribbon/My Strip" key separately for each user. If you want to move this data from one machine to another: think about serialization of user(I am not sure if it will serialized properly), moving whole Core database or copying values from aspnet_Profile table(is not convenient as values are serialized).

Sample code, how you can access these values:

```
var key = "/Current_User/Ribbon/My Strip";
var username = Sitecore.Context.GetUserName();
key = key.Replace("Current_User", username);
Response.Write("Key:" + key);
Response.Write("Registry:" + Registry.GetString(key));
Response.Write("Profile:" + Sitecore.Context.User.Profile[key]);
```

Under hood *Registry.GetString(key)* calls *Sitecore.Context.User.Profile[key*].

Sorry, you will not be able to find it in Core database and put it to package....

Comment: Thanks Anton. I'm doing some digging and trying to understand. Is 'Current_User' the same as 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal {Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User'?

Comment: I am able to get some user values from `Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName("gregory", true);` but i don't see any 'Ribbon' yet

Comment: Also, I'm looking here for info on accessing Registry [link](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2015/01/optimize-performance-on-login-to-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx)

Comment: `Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Registry.GetValue("/Current_User/Ribbon/My Strip") //? ` progress...i think

Comment: Forgot to mention that you should replace "Current_User" with username in which you are interested in. I have updated answer with code sample.

Comment: Thanks Anton. I've put it on a sideburner for now and will get back to it shortly.